# Migrate Apache Tiles definition to JavaConfig

Tags: spring, apache-tiles, spring-java-config

I'm currently migrating my Spring project to JavaConfig. Now there is still the `tiles.xml` which contains the tiles definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <!-- Layouts -->
    <definition name = "template.base" template = "/WEB-INF/views/layout/template.jsp" />

    <!-- Example Controller -->
    <definition name = "test" extends = "template.base" />

</tiles-definitions>
```

Is it possible to translate that XML configuration file to the new JavaConfig standard?